# Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value with Core Data

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, swift3, ensembles

So I have been updating my code for Swift 3.0 and when the app is opened I sync with iCloud and execute a fetch request.

However I get the optional error for the following

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
     appDelegate.syncWithCompletion { (completed) -> Void in
}
```

Which executes the following function in the appDelegate

```
func syncWithCompletion(_ completion:@escaping (_ completed:Bool) -> Void) {

      if !ensemble.isLeeched {
            ensemble.leechPersistentStore { error in
                if error != nil {
                    print("cannot leech \(error!.localizedDescription)")
                    completion(false)
                }
                else {
                    print("leached!!")
                    completion(true)
                }
            }
      }
      else {
            ensemble.merge{ error in
                if error != nil {
                    print("cannot merge \(error!.localizedDescription)")
                    completion(false)
                }
                else {
                    print("merged!!")
                    completion(true)
                    //NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("Updated-DB", object: nil)
                }
           }
      }
}
```

I am not sure what the optional error is for, Xcode updated the function header when migrating.

UPDATE:

So apparently the following have a nil value

[image]

But I am unsure what is causing this since the Swift 3 migration

Comment: Put all-exertions breakpoint in xCode, and tell us please where is exactly your error.

Comment: @PavelGatilov I have updated the question, and I am about to double check what else got changed when migrating

Comment: but, where exactly it crashes?

Answer (score 1):

So I found that the error was because of the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` function in the delegate. The function was not migrated correctly.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: Any]?) -> Bool {
```

I created a new project and used the following instead

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
```

and it worked. This is because the following was not being called therefore my core data stack was not set up

```
self.setupCoreData()
```

Comment: Why don't you use the (automatically) lazy initialized Core Data Stack as suggested in the Apple template?